# Pass Dynamic Variable to highlightResults in Autocomplete.js

Tags: autocomplete, vuejs2, algolia

I'm building a typeahead component for my Vue application that searches Algolia, which has several different indexes to search in different places, so I've created props to be passed in to set the input placeholder, search index, and displayKey.

All works well except my highlighting function for suggestions.

I'm sure this is something simple but I can't get the highlight return to pick up the dynamic prop passed in.

```
$('.typeahead').autocomplete({ hint: false }, [{
    source: $.fn.autocomplete.sources.hits(this.client, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
    displayKey: this.display,
    templates: {
        suggestion: (suggestion) => {
            return suggestion._highlightResult.{this.display goes here}.value;
        }
    }
}]).on('autocomplete:selected', (event, suggestion, dataset) => {
    console.log(suggestion, dataset);
})
```

If I omit the highlighting all works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it was simple, call it via array key instead of dot notation.

`return suggestion._highlightResult[this.display].value;`